# Window creation failed - LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME) Fails C++

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, porting, visual-c++-6

I'm in the middle of upgrading some windows applications (Legacy Code) from VC 6 to VS2010. Most of the applications compiled and would run after cleaning up expected conversion errors, but I'm having a lot of trouble with this. Here is where LoadFrame() fails and the application exits. The error returned here is 0.

```
     CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;// Create main MDI Frame window
     if (!pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME))
         DWORD err = GetLastError();
     return FALSE;
```

Here is the LoadFrame() function from above:(pParentWnd and pContext are both Null on entering the function and I don't understand why?)

```
BOOL CMDIFrameWnd::LoadFrame(UINT nIDResource, DWORD dwDefaultStyle,
CWnd* pParentWnd, CCreateContext* pContext)
{
    if (!CFrameWnd::LoadFrame(nIDResource, dwDefaultStyle,
      pParentWnd, pContext))
        return FALSE;

    // save menu to use when no active MDI child window is present
    ASSERT(m_hWnd != NULL);
    m_hMenuDefault = ::GetMenu(m_hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}
```

After stepping through the LoadFrame and examining the create methods, I discovered that this is where the error occurs here: HWND hWnd = ::AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(..) I noted that cs.hwndParent and cs.hMenu are both showing this error "unused = CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated". I know that this error can mean that the expression is referring to memory outside the programs address space, but I don't see this being the issue.I have seen other issues online which are similar to this, but nothing has helped me understand the problem.

```
BOOL CWnd::CreateEx(DWORD dwExStyle, LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
LPCTSTR lpszWindowName, DWORD dwStyle,
int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight,
HWND hWndParent, HMENU nIDorHMenu, LPVOID lpParam)
{
    ASSERT(lpszClassName == NULL || AfxIsValidString(lpszClassName) || 
        AfxIsValidAtom(lpszClassName));
    ENSURE_ARG(lpszWindowName == NULL || AfxIsValidString(lpszWindowName));

    // allow modification of several common create parameters
    CREATESTRUCT cs;
    cs.dwExStyle = dwExStyle;
    cs.lpszClass = lpszClassName;
    cs.lpszName = lpszWindowName;
    cs.style = dwStyle;
    cs.x = x;
    cs.y = y;
    cs.cx = nWidth;
    cs.cy = nHeight;
    cs.hwndParent = hWndParent;
    cs.hMenu = nIDorHMenu;
    cs.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
    cs.lpCreateParams = lpParam;

    if (!PreCreateWindow(cs))
    {
        PostNcDestroy();
        return FALSE;
    }

AfxHookWindowCreate(this);
HWND hWnd = ::AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(cs.dwExStyle, cs.lpszClass,
        cs.lpszName, cs.style, cs.x, cs.y, cs.cx, cs.cy,
        cs.hwndParent, cs.hMenu, cs.hInstance, cs.lpCreateParams); // RMC here's the error

GetLastError());
DWORD err = GetLastError();

#ifdef _DEBUG
if (hWnd == NULL)
{
    TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: Window creation failed: GetLastError returns 0x%8.8X\n",
        GetLastError());
}
```

The problem is stemming from the LoadFrame() where the Parent Window and Context are Null. Why are they "null/???"? (This application runs fine in VC 6, so it has to be a result of the upgrade) If someone has seen this issue or has any information that may enlighten me about the problem, I would be extremely grateful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that this is internal MFC library code that's failing. That's really strange. My first thought is that there's something badly wrong with your environment. Can you create and build a *new* application, without migrating anything?

Comment: I had somewhat similar issue a while ago when my print preview will not work after upgrading application fro VC6 to VS2010 and it will crash. I discovered the internal of MFC print preview had changed which was causing the crash. I remember I had to drive my own print preview window to fix that issue and I was quite proud of that. So what I would suggest is compare the MFC `framework`functions of VS2010 with that of VC6 and notice what has changed and plan accordingly.

Comment: Have a look in `CMainFrame::OnCreate()` to see if any sub-component is failing to create and returning -1.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes it appears to be internal MFC. That's what I had thought also, but I can create and build a new application with no problems? This program is dependant on a .dll, could this have some implications on the window creation?

Comment: @zadane I have checked the VC6 functions against 2010, and everything appears to be correct? I really don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: @user1793036 The window creation fails here: `AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(..)` so my program never reaches `OnCreate()`. `AfxCtxCreateWindowEx(..)` sets my hWnd to Null and `GetLastError()` returns a 0. 
I just don't understand why `pParentWnd` and `pContext` are null? Might it have something to do with `IDR_MAINFRAME`. As it is being passed as an argument to `LoadFrame()`?

Comment: Is it SDI or MDI? You should also pay attention to the fact in VS2010 each MDI opens in a new window as opposed to MDI in VC6.

Comment: @zadane It's MDI. So does that mean that the method of creating a new MDI window in VC6 differs from than that of MDI in VS2010? Should I be catering for each new window?

Comment: @zadane It turns out that my library path (Linker -> Additional Dependencies) contained a library which supported SDI opposed to MDI. As well as that, the MDI library was an older version which caused errors. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my library path (Linker -> Additional Dependencies) contained a library which supported SDI(Single-Document Interface) opposed to MDI(Multiple-Document Interface). As well as that, the library for MDI was an older version (VC6) which did not support the new MDI methods that are used in Visual Studio 2010.