# What could cause LoadFrame to return false

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

There is a current answer, which may be my problem - like the previous questioner, I'm upgrading legacy code only from 20 years ago, now.  In 2014, Ryan McCloskey wrote [Window creation failed - LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME) Fails C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157469/window-creation-failed-loadframeidr-mainframe-fails-c)
    I'm not sure I have the same problem.  There are other examples of this problem on other sites, always occurring when upgrading legacy code, but everybody's solution is different.
    I am unable to step into the LoadFrame code because I get the error xxxxx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file for 30 dlls.  I do not get this error when I use a totally new project.
    I created this project "from existing files," and I'm wondering if either I did not select an option I needed or selected one I shouldn't have.

If my problem is the same as Mr. McCloskeys, I need to know:  what was the wrong library and what should be the correct library.  I'm using Visual Studio 2017, not 2010, as he was using.  Once I determine what library to use (assuming that this is still the same problem, which it sure looks like), how do I set the correct library in V.S. 2017.

The code is below my signature.

Thank you.

Linda

```
HWND  app_hwnd       = NULL;    
DWORD val_type       = REG_SZ;
char  path[MAX_PATH] = {NULL};
DWORD buff_size      = MAX_PATH;
CMultiDocTemplate *pDocTemplate;
    /* find running application, if any */
app_hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, CStrings::ServerAppTitle);


if(app_hwnd != NULL)
{
    /* application already running, generate warning and exit */
    ::MessageBox(NULL, CStrings::EMRunning, CStrings::Warning,
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    exit(1);
}


#ifdef _DEBUG
    afxMemDF |= checkAlwaysMemDF;   // Check for memory overwrite.
#endif
AfxEnableControlContainer();    

UINT nIDResource = IDR_EMNTTYPE;

// we need to hold RDC template to force RDC creation at startup
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
        nIDResource,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CCMetRDoc),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CCMRChFrm),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CCMRView));
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);


// create main MDI Frame window
CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame(this);

EM_ASSERT(pMainFrame);


if (!pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME)) {
```

Comment: Please describe your own problem and show relevant code. Add a link to the other question/answer.

Comment: Your title gives more info than the rest of the text. Just look into the debug output. Run the program in the debugger and step into LoadFrame. You have the source code! It isn't as complicated.You will see the problem. Maybe a simple resource is missing.

Comment: To all, Thank you for your feedback.  Below is the code.  I can't step into LoadFrame because I

Answer (score 0):

To all, 
      I fixed my problem by merging my code with a standard project created by Visual Studio 2017.  The problem appears to be in the new required standard initialization.   Since, ultimately, I will be getting rid of the user interface, but need a minimal one for now, I just used the generated MainFrm and ChildFrm classes,
     When I built this in the new project directory, I got many errors related to wchar - I'm assuming a 64 vs 32 bit issue.  I solved this by copying my merged files into a new directory, and creating a project from existing files, since the result matches my customer's needs.

Linda